# Xamarin cosmos DB not working when Deploy on IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I working on Xamarin forms and I'am using [Microsoft Cosmod Db](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos) database to store and read data.

In the app I can access/write to my cosmos db database in Debug and Release mode when using IOS and Android Simulator.

But once I deploy on Google Play and **App Store connect** I still can access to my database on Android but not **on IOS** when I try to read data sometimes it crashs or nothing happen

My question : I do not understand why **Cosmos db Nuget package** is not working on IOS once my App is **deploy for test** in App Store connect.

When Using raygun.io to catch my error

Here is the exception :

```
Lealtd.MyPages.MyAuthentification.LeafProfileParameter.MyParamPage() in <aa0ef9de4404408f83484774998ac15a#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Lealtd.MyPages.MyAuthentification.LeafProfileParameter..ctor() in <aa0ef9de4404408f83484774998ac15a#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Lealtd.MyPages.MyAuthentification.LeafInPage.OnUserLeafIn() in <aa0ef9de4404408f83484774998ac15a#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0(System.Object state) in <66c50f4174694147beb2fbedff89d188#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply() in <c07d1d2ff2fb499fb8eca9a33aeb3c2e#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(System.String[] args, System.Type principalClass, System.Type delegateClass) in <c07d1d2ff2fb499fb8eca9a33aeb3c2e#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Lealtd.iOS.Application.Main(System.String[] args) in <3eed6dbecd10466db73945963e82109c#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
```

Here is the stack trace  :

```
    System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.LogicalGetData(System.String ) in <66c50f4174694147beb2fbedff89d188#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
System.Diagnostics.CorrelationManager.get_ActivityId() in <9346215e3717414fb21df612b5dd4279#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ActivityScope..ctor(System.Guid activityId) in <b59e9dd3c16f4591867b773a543b41c5#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync[TResult](Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.ITrace trace, System.Func`2[T,TResult] task, System.Func`2[T,TResult] openTelemetry, System.String operationName, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestOptions requestOptions) in <b59e9dd3c16f4591867b773a543b41c5#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore+<>c__DisplayClass31_0`1[TResult].<OperationHelperWithRootTraceWithSynchronizationContextAsync>b__0() in <b59e9dd3c16f4591867b773a543b41c5#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Lealtd.MyPages.WordPage.MyWordPage.ExecuteRefreshCommandAsyncPulled() in <aa0ef9de4404408f83484774998ac15a#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0(System.Object state) in <66c50f4174694147beb2fbedff89d188#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply() in <c07d1d2ff2fb499fb8eca9a33aeb3c2e#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(System.String[] args, System.Type principalClass, System.Type delegateClass) in <c07d1d2ff2fb499fb8eca9a33aeb3c2e#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
Lealtd.iOS.Application.Main(System.String[] args) in <3eed6dbecd10466db73945963e82109c#c3f844596a550d3270e6f8cf3e1cb01a>
```

I have found this link saying that to make cosmos db work I need to pour Linker behaviour to "don't link" - [Don't Link required with Cosmos DB SDK V3 on iOS #8948](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8948)

When I do it I have this error :

```
Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll].
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
            System.Numerics.Vectors
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        /Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll".
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll
            /Users/x/Documents/Entreprise /MyApps/Leaf/lealtd/lealtd/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/lealtd.dll
        /Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Core.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Core.dll".
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Core.dll
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll
            /Users/x/Documents/Entreprise /MyApps/Leaf/lealtd/lealtd/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/lealtd.dll
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.dll
        /Users/x/.nuget/packages/system.text.json/4.6.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Text.Json.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/x/.nuget/packages/system.text.json/4.6.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Text.Json.dll".
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/system.text.json/4.6.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Text.Json.dll
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/azure.core/1.19.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Azure.Core.dll
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.cosmos/3.31.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll
            /Users/x/Documents/Entreprise /MyApps/Leaf/lealtd/lealtd/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/lealtd.dll
            /Users/x/.nuget/packages/system.memory.data/1.0.2/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Memory.Data.dll
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you get an error or exception?  Does it crash?  What specifically is it doing (or not doing)?

Comment: Once my app is deploy on IOS. I download it on my phone. When i try to read data  Sometimes it crashs or nothing happen

Comment: That is incredibly relevant information that should have been included in your original post.  You need to figure out why it's crashing.  Add exception handling and logging to capture the details of the crash.  You could simply display any caught exceptions in the UI, or log them to the console and view them with XCode, or use a service like raygun.io or appcenter.ms to log them.

Comment: I am trying it to see if I can fix

Comment: You can't fix it if you don't know what the problem is.  I suggested multiple things you should try to determine what the root problem is.

Comment: Yes I am trying every one of them to see If I can get something

Comment: that is the stack trace, where is the actual exception?

Comment: @Jason I have found this link saying cosmos db only works when linker behavior is on "don't link"; I have done it but when deploying I have an error (see question updated)

Comment: That is an informational message, not a build error

Comment: I do not know what else I can do ...

Comment: That message should not prevent you from deploying.  It's purely informational

Comment: @Jason How can I see what prevent me from deploying  ?

Comment: You’ll have to look at the logs.  In my experience that message does not indicate the build failed.

Comment: @Jason Device logs also is not showing me the issue